# Domain object referenced by two Aggregate roots

Tags: domain-driven-design

i have designed a model for a website with the following domain objects:

Article <>
Event <> (like festival, ...)
Comment <> (can be created for articles and events)

Where do i put the Comment-Domain Object in the model?
Should it stay alone or use it's own aggregate?
But a comment makes no sense without an article or an event....

Thanks Mario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly DDD doesn't prevent two aggregate roots to reference the same domain object. As long as the object is not part of both the aggregate root boundaries.

In this case I would consider to create an `ArticleComment` and `EventComment` objects, each belonging to their relevant aggregate roots.  This should be clearer working with a comment object that only applies to one type being commented on.  You can still enforce common data and behaviour by having an abstract `Comment` class.

Comment: ... and since the comments can't live outside an «entity», make them «value object»s.